# How to change the _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE of tint2

Tags: c++, linux, xorg

I am working on creating a custom Linux desktop based off of Openbox, using Compton as my compositor. I would like to make my taskbar, https://github.com/chazmcgarvey/tint2, of the window type _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL instead of _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: That all depends upon what toolkit you are using: xlib, or xcb.

Comment: If I am using xlib, how would I do it?

Comment: Use XChangeProperty, http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XChangeProperty.html. This is just an ordinary window property. Use XInternAtom to obtain the atom for _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE and _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL, then just use XChangeProperty() to set this property.